# Logging from a Hangfire scheduled background job with NLog

Tags: c#, .net, nlog, hangfire

So my problem is as follows: The method/function I'm scheduling to/with Hangfire performs a lot of logging of relevant information using NLog. When running the method without hangfire I'm getting all the logging information i want, but when i schedule the method with hangfire all of this logging is lost.

I am aware that Hangfire use NLog (or whatever else logging framework you prefer) for its own logging purposes. I'm using Hangfire from an ASP.NET MVC4 Web Application. I'm using Ninject and setting hangfire up using the OWIN Startup class which currently looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
    app.UseHangfire(config =>
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyModule());
        config.UseNinjectActivator(kernel);
        config.UseSqlServerStorage("Context");
        LogProvider.SetCurrentLogProvider(new NLogLogProvider());
        config.UseServer();
    });
   }
}
```

What I'm trying to get done is that Hangfire can do its own logging, while my scheduled job also get all of its logging done, I'm not concerned with it being in one or several files. At the moment Hangfire is doing its logging correctly i.e.:

```
2015-02-25 14:32:41.4400|TRACE|Hangfire.Server.AutomaticRetryServerComponentWrapper|Sending start request for server component 'Server Bootstrapper'...
```

etc.

But the logging from the scheduled job is nowhere to be seen.

What im trying to ask is: How do i do logging from the scheduled method/job? My guess is that I'm missing a depedency/context somewhere but i really have no clue atm.

Comment: Were you able to identify the issue?

Comment: @Nediarph If you don't have any filter in NLog config file then it should do the job for you. You don't need to set the current log provider for Hangfire as I believe it automatically read the same based on your web.config settings. In addition, what happen when log line is executed during hangfire operation?

Answer (score 0):

Probably NLog cannot find it's config when running in a Hangfire job.

The solution is to:

1. Or load the config with a path, e.g.

   ```cs
   LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration("c:/dir/nlog.config");
   ```
2. Or create the config in C#. See [docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API)

   ```cs
   var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
   config.AddRuleForAllLevels(new FileTarget()
   {
       FileName = "c:/temp/my-logfile.log"
   });
   LogManager.Configuration = config; //apply config
   ```

If that is still an issue, you could troubleshoot it with the internal log:

```cs
// set internal log level
InternalLogger.LogLevel = LogLevel.Trace;

// enable internal logging to a file
InternalLogger.LogFile = "c:\\temp\\nlog-internal.log";
```

See [internal log docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging)